# Relationship between HttpContext.Request.Cookies and HttpContext.Response.Cookies

Tags: asp.net, cookies, request, response, httpcontext

I have been experimenting with code that will clear all of the cookies in an `HttpContext.Response`.

Initially, I used this:

```
DateTime cookieExpires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

for (int i = 0; i < HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
{
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(
        new HttpCookie(HttpContext.Request.Cookies[i].Name, null) { Expires = cookieExpires });
}
```

However, this will error with an `OutOfMemoryException` because the `for` loop never exits - each time you add a cookie to the `Response`, it also gets added to the `Request.

The following approach works:

```
DateTime cookieExpires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

List<string> cookieNames = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
{
    cookieNames.Add(HttpContext.Request.Cookies[i].Name);
}

foreach (string cookieName in cookieNames)
{
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(
       new HttpCookie(cookieName, null) { Expires = cookieExpires });
}
```

So, what exactly is the relationship between `HttpContext.Request.Cookies` and `HttpContext.Response.Cookies`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Request.Cookies` contains the complete set of cookies, both those that browser send to the server and those that you just created on the server.

[`Response.Cookies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies.aspx) contains the cookies that the server will send back.
This collection starts out empty and should be changed to modify the browser's cookies.

The documentation states:

> ASP.NET includes two intrinsic cookie
>   collections. The collection accessed
>   through the Cookies collection of
>   HttpRequest contains cookies
>   transmitted by the client to the
>   server in the Cookie header. The
>   collection accessed through the
>   Cookies collection of HttpResponse
>   contains new cookies created on the
>   server and transmitted to the client
>   in the Set-Cookie header.
>
> After you add a cookie by using the
>   HttpResponse.Cookies collection, the
>   cookie is immediately available in the
>   HttpRequest.Cookies collection, even
>   if the response has not been sent to
>   the client.

---

Your first code sample should work if you make the `for` loop run backwards.
The new cookies will be added after the end, so the backwards loop would ignore them.